# Executing a shell script from java code and passing data

Tags: java, shell

I have a shell script which executes some jar file. The jar file that is being executed asks some data which has to be entered from the console.
Now i want to create a java program that executes this shell script and also passes the data that is being asked by the jar files at the run-time.
Can anyone guide me on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) and execute a shell script with that process then get the `OutputSTream` from that process through which you can enter the values.

EX:

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(target);
OutputStream out = p1.getOutputStream();
out.write("VALUES".getBytes());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Runtime.exec()** or **ProcessBuilder** to do this. You can refer the following links:

http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/processbuilder_command.htm